# Update Mysql Column Values Using Spark Dataframe

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a mysql table(portfolio) having following two columns(id,Status) with three records.

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Status |
+----+--------+
|  1 |      0 |
|  2 |      1 |
|  3 |      3 |
+----+--------+
```

I would like to update the Status Column from 0 to 1 for Id=1

What i tried in spark scala is :

```
   val portfolio_id =1
   val dbUrl ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=root"
   val prop = new java.util.Properties
   prop.setProperty("user","root")
   prop.setProperty("password","root")

   val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)  

   val portfolioDF=sqlContext.read.jdbc(dbUrl,"portfolio",prop)    
   portfolioDF.registerTempTable("portfolioDF")
   val results =sqlContext.sql("SELECT status from portfolioDF where       id="+portfolio_id)
  //display the record
   results.show()

   //results.insertIntoJDBC(dbUrl, "portfolio", true);
```

Now how do i use the "results" dataframe to modify the "Status"column value.
Or is there any other way by which i can modify the mysql column value through dataframes.
Any guidance would be helpful

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to update the Status Column from 0 to 1 for Id=1

For update use `UPDATE` not `SELECT`

```
UPDATE portfolioDF
SET status = 1
WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Forgot to mention ,i have already tried the above update command the error i receive is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but identifier UPDATE found

UPDATE portfolioDF SET status = 1 WHERE id = 1;